# Load hazelcast imap on application startup

Tags: spring, hazelcast

How can i load `map` in `startup` . I have below config in my `hazelcast.xml` file with `inital mode eager`. But still its loading only when map is first accessed.

```
  <map name="cpMap">
        <map-store enabled="true" initial-mode="EAGER">
            <class-name>com.hazelcast.samples.spring.data.migration.CPLoader</class-name>
        </map-store>
    </map>
```

ALso I have the `map loader` implementation beans as well. I am using spring for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/#initializing-map-on-startup) is pretty clear on that:

> When `getMap()` is first called from any member, initialization starts depending on the value of `InitialLoadMode`. If it is set to `EAGER`, initialization starts on all partitions as soon as the map is touched, *i.e.*, all partitions are loaded when `getMap` is called.

Hence, the map **should be accessed for the map to start populating itself**. If you're using Spring, I'd recommend a `CommandLineRunner` bean to access the map and start the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a map after application ready or any Spring context change event via Spring's EventListener as follow.

```
 @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
 public void myAppReadyMethod() {
        // Call any map
        hz.getMap("myMap"); // Assumed hazelcast instance is already injected
 }
```

You may take a look, Spring application [javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/SpringApplicationEvent.html), context events [javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/package-summary.html).